# How do I fix Missing Web Parts in SharePoint 2010 Foundation

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have 4 missing web parts and the Pages they lived on are gone too. I have no idea what the Web Part names were at all. When I run the following SQL against the Content database in question I get the result posted below it.

How can I correct this problem so the "Missing Server Site Dependencies" Error clears? Can I simply create a Web Part in Visual Studio using the GUIDs here? Is so how do I do that?

```
SELECT webparts.[tp_PageUrlID]
      ,webparts.[tp_PartOrder]
      ,webparts.[tp_ZoneID]
      ,webparts.[tp_WebPartTypeId]
      ,webparts.[tp_Deleted]
  FROM [WSS4_Content].[dbo].[AllWebParts] webparts
  WHERE tp_webparttypeid IN(
'639c4301-2fcb-608f-5597-949e44006d31',
'662be8e0-b184-94ee-ceed-b6df64945830',
'1b79f424-22bb-02a2-084b-ba39707b607b',
'8719c933-c096-a802-0236-d6a641b78489')

RESULTS
755F835F-0DA7-4B63-8946-174BFC1F1CC3    1 Header    8719C933-C096-A802-0236-D6A641B78489    1
E8634AD5-664C-4D65-B502-91826CA5B729    0 Main  662BE8E0-B184-94EE-CEED-B6DF64945830    1
82EA9D30-5318-44EA-9AEB-E19704FB92E8    1 Main  1B79F424-22BB-02A2-084B-BA39707B607B    0
82EA9D30-5318-44EA-9AEB-E19704FB92E8    0 Main  639C4301-2FCB-608F-5597-949E44006D31    0
```

I just realised that I should have posted this on the SharePoint Stack Exchange, which I just did.

Comment: My Conclusion was to remove the records from the Content database as there was no way to recreate the missing web parts. I even contacted Microsoft who could not help me either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Conclusion was to remove the records from the Content database as there was no way to recreate the missing web parts. I even contacted Microsoft who could not help me either.